# Find and replace (increment) ASN.1 BER hex value

Tags: bash, hex, asn.1, ber

I have a long string of hex (converted from BER ASN.1) where I need to find and increment a particular value which is incorrect.

```
<TAG> <LENGTH> <VALUE to INCREMENT>
```

the ASN.1 tag is 84 and the length byte will change from 01 to 02 when the `value > 127dec`. And the value to increment will therefore become 2 bytes.

The value should start at 00.

e.g.

```
- Original file: ...840101...840107...84020085...84020097
- New file:      ...840100...840101...84020080...84020081
```

Any ideas how best to do this, preferably using standard bash commands?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [See how you can format and intend your code correctly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting);

Answer (score 2):

Ilya Etingof hinted at this already, but to be explicit about it, BER uses TAG, LENGTH, VALUE (TLV) encoding, where the VALUE can itself be a TLV.  If you change the length in a TLV that is nested inside a TLV, you will need to update all of the lengths of the enclosing TLVs as well.  It is not a simple search/replace operation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the octet-stream in text work already, you may consider searching/replacing pieces of text with `awk` or `sed`. If you can only use `bash`, may be variable substitution (`${parameter/pattern/string}` or `${parameter:offset:length}`) would work?

Keep in mind however, that BER is quite flexible in the sense that (sometimes) the same data structure may be encoded differently and that would still constitute a valid encoding. The rationale behind that is to allow the encoder to optimize for its very own situation (e.g. save on memory or CPU cycles or on copying etc).

What I am trying to say that depending on your situation there may be a chance that your search/replace logic may fail. The bullet-proof solution would be to fully decode your BER octet stream, change the data structure you need and re-encode it back into BER.

Comment: Thanks for this and point taken that the search/replace logic may fail but it seemed the easiest from my point of view as not familiar with BER encoding / decoding. I have been trying awk / sed but failing to find the right way to get it working.